# on windows, git just hangs instead of accepting my password

Tags: git, bitbucket

I type a git command like this...

C:\xxx\yyy\zzz>git pull

it prompts me for a password.

Password:

I type in the password

nothing happens.

if I hit CTRL-C, it echos my password as an invalid windows command.

it seems like GIT is not reading the password from the command line.

I've googled a lot of stuff about GIT but haven't seen this issue.

generally all password stuff about GIT is really confusing.

note, my "Git Gui" works fine

Comment: Have you tried to wait enough? It might print an actual error (perhaps connection timeout or alike).

Comment: it must be taking A LONG TIME.  hours.